# How to replace the pattern with span element using regex and javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i want to search for a pattern in string extract a value from that matched patter and put that in a span tag how can i do it?

consider string

"i am [1@some user] more text [2@another user]"

i want to match the strings in square brackets

```
[1@some user] [2@another user] and extract the string after @
```

so it should be "some user" "another user"

after that i want to frame a string like

"i am `<span>some user</span>` more text `<span>another user</span>`"

i have tried to use the below code,

```
replace = (str) => {
    const pattern = /\[\d+@(?<name>[^\]\r\n]*)]/g;
    const matched_names = str.matchAll(pattern);
    let names = [];
    for (const match of matched_names) {
        names.push(match.groups.name);
    }
    return str.split(pattern).map((string) => {
        if (names.indexOf(string) >= 0) return <span>{string}</span>;
        return string;
    });
 }
```

the above snippet works but fails if the string is "i am [3@some user]someuser"

basically it fails if the name is same as the one in the square brackets and there is no space between [3@someuser]someuser

how can i fix this. could someoone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
\[\d+@(.*?)\]
```

and `$1` will contain the desired usernames.

https://regex101.com/r/Rv31AC/4

```js
const regex = /\[\d+@(.*?)\]/g;
const str = `i am [1@some user] more text [2@another user]
[1@some user] [2@another user] and extract the string after @ 
i am [3@some user]someuser`;
const subst = `<span>$1</span>`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks i can get the usernames with the regex in the above code. but the problem is this line if (names.indexOf(string) >= 0) return <span>{string}</span>; for this string [3@someuser]someuser the string after split will be the same and then compares it with the tat string and since it finds username at two places it replaces it with span tag where as ideally it should replace only the one in square brackets.

Comment: @someuser2491 You should just use `str.replace()` like my example shows because it produces precisely your desired output.

Comment: and that span should be html content

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use .replace instead of .match?

The regex string `/\[+\d@|]/g` should do exactly what you want?

It works with the examples you have provided with a regex tester I used